# "Quote Shakespeare" or "Quote from Shakespeare"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

If I quote a line from one of Shakespeare's works, will I be **quoting Shakespeare** or **quoting from Shakespeare**? Are "quoting someone" and "quoting from someone" interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

Both are okay. In this particular case, it's undrestood. However, when you *quote someone* you repeat exactly what they have said. And, when you *quote from*, it's their *work*.

That said,

You *quote* Shakesphere, and better you *quote from* his books.